# Stream anaytics complain about type of data sent to powerbi

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I have a query where I specifically convert each and every one of the columns explicitly to either float, datetime or bigint in stream analytics. When I send the output of this query to powerbi I get errors in the Operations Log saying that:
Data type [System.Object] is not supported by Power BI, convert to string type.

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

We improved our diagnostic message recently. If you restart your job, and if this problem repro, it will tell you which column has null value, that's why it is treated the System.Object type. ASA will convert it into null string and send to Power BI.  Please also make sure that you don't have mismatch input field than the one you specify in the query or no null value from your input data. What query you are using?

Comment: It seems like it gives better output now. When I send a string column it says:Message: The column 'filenamepart4' is System.Object type which is not supported by PBI service

Comment: In understand why this error is occurring, but what is the best practice for dealing with null values?  I seem to be unable to convert these values to anything the PBI will accept.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1. In your SELECT clause you can do CASE  IS NULL THEN  ELSE  END AS  (e.g. SELECT CASE Name IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE Name END AS NAME).
2. You can filter out this row in the WHERE clause (e.g. WHERE Name IS NOT NULL).

Hope this helps!

Ziv.